# Why java is also a system/OS name(help doc in python)?

Tags: java, python, operating-system

I'm searching a method in python to show me the platform details. So I find `platform.system()`, but I got shock when I saw [the help doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.system):

> system()
>
> Returns the system/OS name, e.g. 'Linux', 'Windows' or 'Java'.

Any idea on why 'Java' is listed there but not 'Darwin'?

Comment: Probably for Jython.

Comment: Please remember to add the link to the doc when referencing them, I've added the link to Python 3 but if you are using Python 2 then feel free to update this reference

Comment: I've never used Jython, so I can not confirm that...

Comment: Jython seems like a dead project...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Darwin` is indeed one of the possible outputs of the `platform.system()` method. I did a quick Google search and came up with [this](https://pymotw.com/2/platform/).

```
import platform

print 'uname:', platform.uname()
print 'system   :', platform.system()
print 'version  :', platform.version()
```

Java is probably there for Jython implementations, as someone pointed out above.

**EDIT**: Further Googling led me to this:

[image: Jython proof]

`platform.system()` uses `sys.platform`, so I think this is where the `Java` comes from.
This excerpt is from the book **Jython Essentials: Rapid Scripting in Java** and therefore can be regarded as conclusive. [Link included for reference](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Dm1gsjr1gN8C&pg=PA180&lpg=PA180&dq=sys.platform%20java&source=bl&ots=czfqqWn2K7&sig=KZC4WH7rPGrQZraOtWVf9VcHb5c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwih0dmi783RAhUGTI8KHby5CY0Q6AEITTAI#v=onepage&q=sys.platform%20java&f=false).

Comment: Can you confirm that?

Comment: Thanks for the effort on the explanation...I think they should change it to 'Darwin' for Jython seems like a dead project.